# Difference between $httpParamSerializerJQLike and $httpParamSerializer

Tags: angularjs

i dont understand what is main difference between $httpParamSerializerJQLike and $httpParamSerializer and when we can use one of them..
any one help me.. ?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but was looking for it today too and found an answer somewhere else: 

[link](http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/angularjs/24710503.html):

In general, it seems $httpParamSerializer uses less "traditional" url-encoding format than $httpParamSerializerJQLike when it comes to complex data structures.

For example (ignoring percent encoding of brackets):

With an **array** property of a data object such as `{sites:['google', 'Facebook']}`:

- **$httpParamSerializer** would return `sites=google&sites=facebook`
- **$httpParamSerializerJQLike** would return `sites[]=google&sites[]=facebook`

---

With an **object** property of a data object such as `{address: {city: 'LA', country: 'USA'}}`:

- **$httpParamSerializer** would return `address={"city": "LA", country: "USA"}`
- **$httpParamSerializerJQLike** would return `address[city]=LA&address[country]=USA`

Answer (score 1):

See [Olafvv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46070425/395879) how the resulting content differs. But there are 2 important points to add:

Firstly, `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` tries to emulate jQuery's algorithm for producing request data from objects / arrays.

Secondly, `$httpParamSerializerJQLike`(and therefore also jQuery) will produce request data from objects / arrays that is natively parseable by PHP . I.e. the request data will be available as associative array again in PHP's global `$_GET` / `$_POST` variables. If you use `$httpParamSerializer` to generate and pass a string like `sites=google&sites=facebook` to a PHP backend, PHP won't reckognize `sites` as an array but as a single parameter. The second value `facebook` will overwrite the first value `google`. So you have to parse the request data on your own.

However, [it seems the `[]` syntax was introduced by PHP without any standard or specification](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-str.php#76792). I guess, jQuery applied this syntax for AJAX request data due to the popularity of PHP at the time jQuery was first released. Respectively, later AngularJS emulated jQuery's behavior due to jQuery's popularity.